# I want to run each .feature file as single TestNG test using Karate?

Tags: karate

I want to run each `.feature` file as single TestNG test using Karate, how can I do it?

We are using karate to automate REST API's. We have custom listener which will record status of each TestNG test and other information to postgress DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more way running by tags:

```
@CucumberOptions(tags = { "@getVersion" })
public class GetVersionTest extends KarateRunner {

}
```

Feature File:

```
@getVersion
Feature: Testing Rest API with Karate and Java

  Scenario: 
    Given url 'https://......'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match response contains '{version= x.xx.x}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the Karate TestNG support ?  The documentation has details on how to use: https://github.com/intuit/karate#running-with-testng

As the developer of Karate I actually strongly recommend that teams don't use TestNG. My suggestion is that you use the new ['hooks'](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks) feature to call your custom Java code from Karate directly and you won't depend on TestNG or even JUnit.

If you still need a custom way of running, the TestNG support is actually a single class: [`KarateRunner.java`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-testng/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/testng/KarateRunner.java). I really don't know if it runs each feature as a TestNG test or not since I am not a TestNG expert. But you should be able to create your own version of this Java code that does what you want and maybe contribute it back to the project.

Comment: @CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:talos/tests/karatetests/supervisor/gettagvalues/tagvalues-get.feature")
public class GetTagValuesRunner extends KarateRunner {

}
But testng.xml when i put the class name and run it does not recognize as testng class, as there is no annotation @Test, it says zero tests executed

Comment: no idea. all the best. really recommend you don't use TestNG.